# RegSetValueEx: crear un valor DWORD con el tipo de dato BYTE

Tags: c, windows, winapi

En la [documentación oficial de Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923(v=vs.85).aspx) está definida la función `RegSetValueEx` de la **API de Windows** así:

```
LONG WINAPI RegSetValueEx(
  _In_             HKEY    hKey,
  _In_opt_         LPCTSTR lpValueName,
  _Reserved_       DWORD   Reserved,
  _In_             DWORD   dwType,
  _In_       const BYTE    *lpData,
  _In_             DWORD   cbData
);
```

Como pueden ver, el valor `*lpData`, creado para almacenar el dato del valor, está definido como un const `BYTE`, el cual se declara en `WinDef.h` como `unsigned char`.

Así están mis definiciones:

```
//Variables needed for registry value creation.
PTCHAR regValueName = TEXT("dwValue");
DWORD regValueType = REG_DWORD;
BYTE regData = 1;
const BYTE *pRegData = &regData;
DWORD dataSize = sizeof(regData);
```

Así estoy llamando a la función RegSetValueEx:

```
setValueKey = RegSetValueEx(*pHandleResult, regValueName, reserved,
                            regValueType, pRegData, dataSize);
```

El `*pHandleResult` es un `HANDLE` devuelto por `RegOpenKeyEx`, pero no estoy mostrando ese código aquí para no hacer el código demasiado largo.

Yo deseo crear un valor DWORD con contenido de 1, y la función lo crea, pero el contenido termina siendo este texto:

> «Invalid (DWORD 32 bit) value»

[image: Resultado de RegSetValueEx]

Yo sé que puedo definir el `regData` como un `DWORD`, asignarle 1 y así funcionaría, mas quiero saber básicamente por qué no me funciona utilizando el dato que está declarado por la documentación oficial de Microsoft. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Les agradezco la ayuda. Si necesitan alguna otra información, con gusto la daré.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un entero en la jerga de la API es un DWORD es decir una palabra doble. Cada palabra (WORD) es de 2 bytes, por ende un DWORD es de 4 bytes, o sea 32 bit, Un entero de 32 bit.

Así las cosas necesitamos definir las siguientes variables y llamar la función

```
HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;  
LPCTSTR lpValueName = L"MyDemoValue";//L es para indicar que es una cadena larga (L=long) equivale a decir una cadena unicode  
DWORD Reserved=0;  
DWORD dwType = REG_DWORD;  
DWORD Value = 1;  
DWORD cbData = sizeof(Value);  
RegSetValueEx(hKey, lpValueName, Reserved, dwType, (const BYTE *) &Value, cbData);
```

Fíjense que la función requiere que lpData sea un array de BYTE pero le estamos pasando un `DWORD`(entero) aplicandole alguna especie de CAST DEL INFIERNO!... recueden C++ = control granular de la memoria.

Todo dato, CUALQUIERA QUE SEA, a la final no es sino un montón de bytes, así que hemos hecho lo siguiente:

Nuestro dato es el número 1 guardado en Value `&Value` no es más que la dirección de memoria de la variable Value.

Pero esa dirección de memoria sería de tipo `DWORD *,` claro el tipo de dato es `DWORD` por ende el apuintador debe ser así La función no espera un `DWORD *` espera un `BYTE *`

Pero a la final TODO son bytes así que un `DWORD *` le podemos hacer casting a `BYTE *` sin problema

Alguien me hizo esa misma pregunta hace in par de años, así que tengo in artículo complete y super detallado al respecto.

### [Un vistazo a la función de RegSetValueEx de la API de Windows](https://juank.io/vistazo-funcion-regsetvalueex-api-windows/)

Comment: Pero, ¿por qué no enviarle directamente un BYTE? Es decir, hacer que Value sea de tipo BYTE, crear su apuntador y enviarlo a la función. ¿Para qué hacer el cast si se puede utilizar el tipo de datos directamente?

Comment: porque si lo creas así el ordén de los bytes que representan el DWORD no coincidira con el valor esperado por lpdata. si le pasas un byte, pues un byte es un byte, quieres crear uncampo DWORD entonces el 1 debe estar en 4 bytes y estos deben estar en notación little indian, es decir corresponderian a un byte[] [1,0,0,0] , los bytes menos significativos primero.